# Find a formula to approximate $f''(x_0)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

> Find a formula to approximate $f''(x_0)$ which uses $f( x_0),f\left(x_0+\frac{h}{2}\right)$ and $f(x+2h)$.

My workings so far,

$$f''(x) \approx Af(x+2h) + B(x) + C f\left(x_0+\frac{h}{2}\right)$$

Expand in a Taylor series:

$$Af(x+2h) = Af(x) +2Ahf(x) + 2Ah^2f(x)$$
Do I need to solve this using the method of undetermined coefficients? I tried to do this with the rest but I am stuck!.

Comment: Do this for the third term, and then compare coefficients in the linear combinations. What equations do you get?

Comment: what do you mean by that? what term?

Comment: @LutzL could you show how this is done?

Comment: The Taylor expansion of $f(x_0+h/2)$. It is quite similar to what you already did. Then group by value, first and second derivative at $x_0$.

Comment: You can use undetermined coefficients if you want, I would prefer to use the two obvious formulae for approximating $f'(x_0)$ and subtract, then look for the coefficient of $f''(x_0)$.

Comment: @user10354138 could you show how that is done?

Comment: @Lutz so $$Cf(x+\frac{h}{2}) = Cf(x) + f'(x+\frac{h}{2})(x-(x+\frac{h}{2}) + \frac{f''(x+\frac{h}{2})}{2!}(x-(x+\frac{h}{2})^2$$ then what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have two obvious formulae for approximating $\require{cancel}f'(x_0)$:
\begin{align}
f'(x_0)&\approx \frac{f(x_0+2h)-f(x_0)}{2h}\tag{1}\label{1sta}\\
f'(x_0)&\approx \frac{f(x_0+h/2)-f(x_0)}{h/2}\tag{2}\label{1stb}
\end{align}
When you Taylor expand the RHS of both equations, there are no contribution from $f(x_0)$ and the contribution from $f'(x_0)$ are the same (this is why they approximate $f'(x_0)$).  So it makes sense to try subtracting one from another, and the "next" derivative term $f''(x_0)$ will appear (in general, there won't be any miraculous cancellation):
\begin{align}
&\frac{f(x_0+2h)-f(x_0)}{2h}-\frac{f(x_0+h/2)-f(x_0)}{h/2}\\
&\approx
\frac{\color{red}{f(x_0)}+\color{blue}{2hf'(x_0)}+\frac12(2h)^2f''(x_0)\color{red}{-f(x_0)}}{2h}\\
&\qquad\qquad-\frac{\color{red}{f(x_0)}+\color{blue}{\frac12hf'(x_0)}+\frac12(\frac12h)^2f''(x_0)\color{red}{-f(x_0)}}{h/2}\tag{3}\label{01cancel}
\\
&=\left[\frac{\frac12(2h)^2}{2h}-\frac{\frac12(\frac12h)^2}{\frac12h}\right]f''(x_0)=\frac34hf''(x_0).
\end{align}
The cancellations in line \eqref{01cancel} are already alluded to above: $f(x_0)$ already don't appear in \eqref{1sta} and \eqref{1stb}, the $f'(x_0)$ cancel because they are the LHS of \eqref{1sta} and \eqref{1stb} which we are subtracting from.
Now rearrange to give an approximation formula for $f''(x_0)$
\begin{align}
f''(x_0)&\approx\frac{\dfrac{f(x_0+2h)-f(x_0)}{2h}-\dfrac{f(x_0+h/2)-f(x_0)}{h/2}}{\frac34h}\\
&=\frac{f(x_0+2h)-4f(x_0+h/2)+3f(x_0)}{\frac32h^2}.
\end{align}

Comment: could you explain "when you taylor expand the rhs of both equations there are no contributions from.. inmore detail?

Comment: very clear explanation now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If we imagine expanding $f$ into a Taylor series about $x_0$, then we have:

$$
f(x_0 + g) \approx f(x_0) + f'(x_0) g + f''(x_0) \frac{g^2}{2} + O(g^3)
$$

Now let's see what happens when we look at this formula for $g=\frac{h}{2}$ and $g=2h$:

\begin{eqnarray*}
f(x_0 + \frac{h}{2}) &\approx& f(x_0) + f'(x_0) \frac{h}{2} + f''(x_0)\frac{h^2}{8} \\
f(x_0 + 2h) &\approx& f(x_0) + f'(x_0)(2h) + f''(x_0) (2h^2)
\end{eqnarray*}

A little manipulation of the equations then can get you an approximation for $f''(x_0)$. (Hint: examine what $4  f(x_0 + \frac{h}{2}) - 3  f(x_0) - f(x_0 + 2h)$ is approximately equal to.)

Comment: how would I manipulate the equations to get the approx.?

Comment: do I need to add or subtract them?